# How do I show information on Google Cast after connecting

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cast

So I went and followed the documentation for Google Cast on iOS. I can connect to the Cast device and all, but I have no idea how I would go about showing data on the Google Cast. The documentation glance over it a bit:

> Once you are connected to the receiver you will be notified. After connecting successfully, you can launch your application.

```
- (void)deviceManagerDidConnect:(GCKDeviceManager *)deviceManager {
 NSLog(@"connected to %@", _selectedDevice.friendlyName);

 [self updateButtonStates];

 // Launch application after getting connected.
 [_deviceManager launchApplication:kReceiverAppID];
}
```

But nothing really helpful regarding custom views.
So, my question is; how do I create a custom view when Casting for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the CastHelloText sample app : https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-ios

In particular, you will need to have a custom receiver and you will need to create a custom namespace so you can send messages to the receiver. The receiver logic can then display the message.

Comment: I did look at the sample app (the code I used in my question was taken from it), but as soon as I connect to a Cast Device, it disconnects.

Comment: Did you use the sample receiver or did you change it in any way?